# Gnuplot: Nested “plot” iteration (“plot for”) with dependent loop indices

Tags: loops, for-loop, gnuplot

I have recently attempted to concisely draw several graphs in a plot using gnuplot and the `plot for ...` syntax. In this case, I needed nested loops because I wanted to pass something like the following index combinations (simplified here) to the `plot` expression:

- `i = 0`, `j = 0`
- `i = 1`, `j = 0`
- `i = 1`, `j = 1`
- `i = 2`, `j = 0`
- `i = 2`, `j = 1`
- `i = 2`, `j = 2`
- and so on.

So `i` loops from `0` to some upper limit `N` and for each iteration of `i`, `j` loops from `0` to `i` (so `i <= j`). I tried doing this with the following:

```
# f(i, j, x) = ...
N = 5
plot for [i=0:N] for [j=0:i] f(i, j, x) title sprintf('j = %d', j)
```

but this only gives five iterations with `j = 0` every time (as shown by the `title`). So it seems that gnuplot only evaluates the `for` expressions once, fixing `i = 0` at the beginning and not re-evaluating to keep up with changing `i` values. Something like this has already been hinted at in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654184/595306) (“in the `plot for ...` structure the second index cannot depend on the first one.”).

Is there a simple way to do what I want in gnuplot (i.e. use the combinations of indices given above with some kind of loop)? There is the `do for { ... }` structure since gnuplot 4.6, but that requires individual statements in its body, so it can’t be used to assemble a single `plot` statement. I suppose one could use `multiplot` to get around this, but I’d like to avoid `multiplot` if possible because it makes things more complicated than seems necessary.

Comment: No, there is no simple way. That's why I proposed that ugly workaround in the answer you linked to ;)

Comment: @Christoph For this specific case there is nice workaround I worked out in my answer below.

Comment: @Miguel Indeed, :) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your problem personally. For your specific problem you can use a mathematical trick. Remap your indices (i,j) to a single index k, such that

```
(0,0) -> (0)
(1,0) -> (1)
(1,1) -> (2)
(2,0) -> (3)
...
```

It can be shown that the relation between i and j and k is

```
k = i*(i+1)/2 + j
```

which can be inverted with a bit of algebra

```
i(k)=floor((sqrt(1+8.*k)-1.)/2.)
j(k)=k-i(k)*(i(k)+1)/2
```

Now, you can use a single index k in your loop

```
N = 5
kmax = N*(N+1)/2 + N
plot for [k=0:kmax] f(i(k), j(k), x) title sprintf('j = %d', j(k))
```

Comment: Of course, this is not really a “simple” solution from a mathematical point of view, but it does allow one to use the simple `plot for ...` syntax without having to deal with `multiplot` or other gnuplot complications. Also, it’s not easily extensible to other cases where the indices depend on each other in different ways. But I’m sure you know that ;-)

So I guess the answer is “No, not without transforming the indices or other workarounds.”

Comment: It is simple in the sense that the expressions are short and transparent. Arriving at the expressions requires a bit more work, so yes you're right. This is just a case-specific solution that relies on the fact that analytic expressions can be obtained for the mapping inversion. For the general case, I would use a variant of the solution given in Christoph's answer (the one you linked in your question).